# Trying to understand Task.ContinueWith()

Tags: c#

I'm trying to understand some (in my eyes) weird behaviour. I have a call to some async method and want to retrieve its result. (`DeleteIndexAsync` return a `Task<bool>`)

```
  var deleteTask = Task.Run(() => DeleteIndexAsync(localItem))
    .ContinueWith(t =>
  {
   //handle and log exceptions       
  }, TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted);

 if (!deleteTask.Result)
```

In this scenario `Result` is `false` and the `Status` is `WaitingForActivation`.

Whereas this code does what I want

```
  var deleteTask = Task.Run(() => DeleteIndexAsync(localItem));
  deleteTask.ContinueWith(t =>
   {
     //handle and log exceptions
     return false;
   }, TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted);

  if (!deleteTask.Result)
```

Can someone explain why? And is it possible to use `async` / `await` instead of `Task` here?

Edit:

```
  var deleteTask = Task.Run(() => ThrowEx());
  bool errorOccurred = false;
  deleteTask.ContinueWith(t =>
   {         
     errorOccurred = true;
   }, TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted);

  if (errorOccurred)
  {
    return true;
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you chain the calls, like in the first example, the value you are assigning to the `deleteTask` variable is actually the second `Task`. This is the one that is supposed to run only on failure of the first task (the one calling `DeleteIndexAsync`).

This is because both `Task.Run` and `Task.ContinueWith` return `Task`s that they create. It explains why in the first example you get `Status == WaitingForActivation`. In the first snippet, accessing `deleteTask.Result` would cause an exception to be thrown. In case `DeleteIndexAsync` threw, it would be an `AggregateException` containing original exception (unless you accessed `t.Exception`), otherwise it would be stating that the "Operation was cancelled" - this is because you try to get the result of the task that was scheduled conditionally and the condition was not met.

If you made method containing the snipped `async` you could do it like this (not tested):

```
bool success = false;
try
{
    success = await DeleteIndexAsync(localItem);
}
catch (Exception) {}

if (!success)
{
    //TODO: handler
}
```

**Regarding question edit:**

Using captured variable should help, but your current solution introduces race condition. In this case it would be better to do like this:

```
var deleteTask = Task.Run(() => ThrowEx());    

try
{
    deleteTask.Wait();
} 
catch (Exception ex)
{
    return true;
}
```

but at this point you can drop the asynchronous call entirely, because you wait for the result immediately - unless this example simplifies work that can be done between `Run` and `Wait`)

Comment: I think checking task.Result to determine whether an error occured or not isn't a good idea aswell? Accessing task.Result throws an exception here... and also the Faulted flag is always false, even when an exception was thrown.

Comment: @user3292642 I don't think I understand? You should access the `Exception` property to swallow the exception.

Comment: I dont want to swallow the exception. I'm already logging it in the continuewith method. After the logging was done, I want to return if an exception was thrown but I dont know how. Checking the Status isnt an option aswell I think.

Comment: Can you check my edit? Would a local variable do the trick? or could it be that the compiler runs over my check before the continuewith method could set the flag to true?

Comment: @user3292642 I have made some edits, please check them

Comment: thx for your help. Im using your solution with the await keyword and its working as expected. I would really like to get rid of the Task.Run/Wait methods and use async/await but I'm calling this from a synchronous method and i cannot change the method signature to use async keyword. So i think Im not able to await the DeleteIndexAsync method here (as in your first example), am I?

Comment: @user3292642 it's impossible to use `await` without `async` in the signature, so you will have to wait for the `DeleteIndexAsync` to finish before your method ends or make the `Task` that runs it a class member and `Wait` for it somewhere else

Answer (score 2):

> I have a call to some async method and want to retrieve its result.

[The best way to do this is with `await`, not `Result`](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html).

> Can someone explain why?

In the first example, `deleteTask` is the task returned from `Task.Run`. In the second example, `deleteTask` is the task returned from `ContinueWith`. This task never actually executes unless `DeleteIndexAsync` throws an exception.

> And is it possible to use async / await instead of Task here?

Yes, that's the best approach. When working with asynchronous code, you should always [use `await` instead of `ContinueWith`](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2015/01/a-tour-of-task-part-7-continuations.html). In this case, the `TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted` means you should put the continuation code in a `catch` block after the `await`:

```
bool deleteResult;
try
{
  deleteResult = await Task.Run(() => DeleteIndexAsync(localItem));
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
  //handle and log exceptions
}
if (!deleteResult)
  ...
```

Or, since it looks like `DeleteIndexAsync` is asynchronous, removing `Task.Run` would be more appropriate:

```
bool deleteResult;
try
{
  deleteResult = await DeleteIndexAsync(localItem);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
  //handle and log exceptions
}
if (!deleteResult)
  ...
```